# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: key, public

getting this error while up spring boot application, i try the lot as solution provide by net , but still getting same , can any buddy help with this

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)